# Filtering a GridView with drop downs

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I've been stuck on this for too long, and my Google-Fu is failing me. I'm new to C# and .Net, so I'm getting pretty frustrated here.

Here's what I have so far:

A method called GetData populates a DataSet, then I create a DataTable from that.

I bind the DataTable to the GridView, which is then made sortable. The table and sorting work fine, but I need to have drop down filtering on a few of the columns, but I can't get anything to work.

My ASP:

```
<asp:GridView id="gvEvaluator" Runat="server" Width="750" tooltip="Evaluator Status"     AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
EnableViewState="true" 
HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#000000"
HeaderStyle-BackColor="#CCCCCC" 
FooterStyle-ForeColor="#000000" 
FooterStyle-BackColor="#CCCCCC" 
Font-Size="8pt" 
Font-Names="Verdana" 
CellSpacing="0" 
CellPadding="3" 
ShowFooter="true" 
AllowSorting="true" 
GridLines="Both" 
BorderColor="#ffffff" 
BackColor="#ffffff"
ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
visible="true"
AllowPaging="false"
AllowCustomPaging="false"
OnSorting="GridView_Sorting">

    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<strong>Term</strong>"
            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Bottom"
            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="top" >
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTerm"
                        runat="server"
                        visible="true"
                        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTermChanged"
                        AutoPostBack="true"
                        DataSourceID="gvEvaluator">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </HeaderTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Dept" HeaderText="Dept" SortExpression="Dept></asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Course" HeaderText="Course" SortExpression="Course"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Section" HeaderText="Section"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Evaluator" HeaderText="Evaluator" SortExpression="Evaluator"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Type" HeaderText="Evaluator Type"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Email_Address" Visible="false"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Days_Since_Login" HeaderText="Days Since Login"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Required_Work" HeaderText="Required Work" SortExpression="Required_Work"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Total_Assigned" HeaderText="Total Assigned" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Total_Not_Started" HeaderText="Total Not Started" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Total_in_Progress" HeaderText="Total in Progress" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Total_Complete" HeaderText="Total Complete" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField DataField="eval_id" Visible="false"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<strong>Need Reminder<strong>" ItemStyle-Width="250px">
                  <ItemTemplate>
                  <label for="hyplEvaluator" class="hide">Email Evaluator</label> 
                  <asp:HyperLink ID="hyplEvaluator" runat="server" CssClass="BodyLink" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Need_Reminder")%>' NavigateUrl='' />
                  </ItemTemplate>
                  </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And my C#:

```
protected void getEvaluatorStatus()
    {
        try
        {
            ds = GetData();
            DataTable myTable = ds.Tables[0];
            if (myTable.Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                gvEvaluator.DataSource = ds;
                gvEvaluator.DataBind();
                gvEvaluator.Visible = true;
                lblNoAssignment.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                lblNoAssignment.Visible = true;
                gvEvaluator.Visible = false;
            }

            //Adds attributes to hyplEmailContact

            for (int i = 0; i < gvEvaluator.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string inSenderID = Convert.ToString(meth.decrypt(Session["UserID"].ToString(), Convert.ToString(Session["University"]), Convert.ToString(Session["Department"])));
                string inRecptID = Convert.ToString(gvEvaluator.Rows[i].Cells[10].Text);

                //custom string of attributes above
                string customStr = "inSenderID=" + inSenderID + ",inRecptID=" + inRecptID;

                //Adds the NavigateURL for Contact command to pass variables/attributes 
                HyperLink hyplEmailContact = (HyperLink)gvEvaluator.Rows[i].FindControl("hyplEvaluator");
                hyplEmailContact.NavigateUrl = "javascript:openEmailGeneral(" + customStr + ")";

            } //End for loop 

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Session["Error_Code"] = ex;
            Response.Redirect("../Error.aspx");
        }
```

I'm just a lowly bug squasher, so the only code I personally wrote was creating the GridView (from a DataGrid), the GetData method, making it sortable, and making the data exportable.

Comment: It might help if you posted some sample code and markup.

Comment: it would probably be easier if you pasted your code and the markup Template that corresponds to the GridView

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

1. Handle the `ddlTermChanged` changed event:
2. Grab the new selected value in the dropdown list as so

   ```
   protected void ddlTermChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
       var newValue = ddlTerm.SelectedValue;
       //see step 3 below
   }
   ```
3. Now filter the data and rebind it to the Gridview; something like:

   ```
   protected void ddlTermChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
       var newValue = ddlTerm.SelectedValue;
       DataTable t=  GetDataByID(newValue);
       gvEvaluator.DataSource=t;
       gvEvaluator.DataBind();
   }
   ```

On a separate note, all the transformations you are doing on the Gridview inside the `getEvaluatorStatus` method should have been handled in the `OnRowDataBound` event. By doing it the way you did it, every time you rebind the data (as in the case of filtering) you'll have to repeat the code inside the `getEvaluatorStatus` to do the transformations  again. If you do it `OnRowDataBound` you won't have to repeat code as the event is raised for every row as it is being bound.

Comment: Ok, that points me in the right direction, but brings up the issue I've been having the most trouble with: How do I populate each drop down list? I tried to do it by having a method called ddlPopulateTerm, binding the datatable to it, then doing something like: 

ddlTerm.DataTextField = ds.Tables[0].Columns[0].ToString();

But that's not working

And thank you!